# Main character can use sound/vibration to move objects

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book around 2000. The main character was a young fellow was trained by an older man to use powers of sound/vibration. They practiced to move large rocks. He would use a stick to create sound/vibration and be able to control an object by focusing on it.

I think he late learned to use verbal commands too, sort of like a magician would say "*Abracadabra*", words create vibration too which gives control.

There would be a society of people who can do similar things and they had a conflict with this man. I can't quite remember how the story goes but I think he was on the run and had a few fights using this power.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ih2gw1Hg2LU

Comment: [Solaris Seethes](https://books.google.com/books?id=zXPkBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT71&lpg=PT71&dq=young+adult+fantasy+using+sound+to+move&source=bl&ots=8JYovjSxVp&sig=ACfU3U38Xp64al8xw02qui5auni75nmeKg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwikjYi-2oHoAhUDsKQKHdLfCv0Q6AEwAHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=using%20sound&f=false)?

Comment: I gave Solaris Seethes a read and it wasn't it. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: This could fit Ben Aaronovitch's _Rivers of London_ series. Have a look at the first one, _[Midnight Riot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rivers_of_London_(novel))_. (Looks like it was published under a different name in the UK.)

Comment: I checked Ben Aaronovitch, it isn't it. I think the theme of the book i am looking for is more medieval. Thank you for suggestions, I know my description in not much to go on.